# Does pyFFTW allow to preserve the input array

Tags: python, python-3.x, fft, fftw, pyfftw

I would like to know whether there's a possiblity to enforce **pyFFTW** (wrapper around FFTW) the **input vector to be preserved** during forward r2c transform.

At least in **original FFTW** the **FFTW_PRESERVE_INPUT** seems to be a default option (look at algorithm-restriction flags here: http://www.fftw.org/doc/Planner-Flags.html )

With pyFFTW's **FFTW.__call__()** one can pass several flags, but only **'FFTW_DESTROY_INPUT'** is listed here: http://hgomersall.github.io/pyFFTW/pyfftw/pyfftw.html#pyfftw.FFTW

Probably, that's not only lapse in documentation because in the source code, in the file *builders/builders.py* there's a bit terrifying statement (line 166):

> overwrite_input: Whether or not the input array can be
>     overwritten during the transform.

Further in the code in file *builders/_utils.py* in definition of a function *_Xfftn*, only destory flag is present:
`if overwrite_input:
     flags.append('FFTW_DESTROY_INPUT')`

**The ultimate question is: knowing that the FFTW_PRESERVE_INPUT cannot be passed with pyFFTW, could I at least rely on the fact that in original FFTW
this flag FFTW_PRESERVE_INPUT is default? Recall the comment quoted above: *"Whether or not the input array can be overwritten"* Does the authors of
pyFFTW wrapper know something more and default FFTW_PRESERVE_INPUT won't work?**

`$ rpm -q fftw
fftw-3.3.4-6.fc23.x86_64`

`>>> pyfftw.__version__
'0.10.1`

Comment: The very genius of the standard FFT is that it is an inplace operation, so it always overwrites the input. If you want to preserve the input, keep a copy of it.

Comment: @roadrunner66 Here http://www.fftw.org/doc/Planner-Flags.html the authors of FFTW allowed 2 args. to be passed: DESTROY_INPUT & PRESERVE_INPUT. They made it for some sake and my question really is ' can I rely on the assumption that PRESERVE is default?'.

Comment: @roadrunner66 I'm asking about preserving the input, because I must perform many forward transforms on very similar vectors, thus instead of setting up each input vector from scratch, I would rather apply tiny changes to single input vector.

Comment: Then put that single input vector into a variable, then apply tiny changes to a copy before submitting that copy to the FFT.

Comment: `overwrite_input` is an instruction from you to `pyFFTW` letting the library know that it's fine to overwrite the input. I don't understand the issue about that argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all the defaults are used unless explicitly requested - this means that unless you request `DESTROY_INPUT`, then `PRESERVE_INPUT` is implicit, *except* in the case where you have a multi-dimensional c2r transform, in which case the input will be destroyed (this is documented in the `Schemes` section of the documentation you linked to, as well as the FFTW docs you linked to).

If you find a case where the input is destroyed and it is not either explicitly requested as such or is not one of the above transforms, this is a bug and should be reported.

The `interfaces` code makes various copies to make sure transforms are preserved when necessary.

My recollection is the planning stage is much looser about protecting arrays - the easiest way of protecting the array is to use the `builders` interface which, unless explicitly advised otherwise, will always store the original array and copy it back in.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this explains everything. When I was posting this question I thought there's a problem on the side of the original FFTW (not pyFFTW) and that's why you're using this `reload_after_transform` in interfaces. Moreover you allowed only one flag *DESTROY* omitting *PRESERVE* and if there was not enough in comment you stated * Whether or not the input array can be overwritten*, what all together convinced me that default settings won't work. Fortunately, that was only misunderstanding. Once again, thak you for this answer and generally for creating *pyFFTW* wrapper.